# Unable to add a PivotField to the DataField

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Ebo_Discount_Fresh_Pivot()

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).AddFields PageFields:=Array("Bill Date", "Promotion_FULL_MRP", "Brand", "Division", "Customer Type")

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Sale Quantity").Orientation = xlDataField
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Net Sale (After Tax)").Orientation = xlDataField

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Division").CurrentPage = _
"APPARELS"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Customer Type").CurrentPage = "POS"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Brand").CurrentPage = _
"RITUKUMAR"

ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Promotion_FULL_MRP").CurrentPage = _
"Promotion"


End Sub
```

When I run the above Macro, I get a Pivot report as seen below:

[image]

We can see that the `Net Sale (After Tax)` PivotField is not added to the DataField. Is it because `(After Tax)` is in brackets?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next`  - do you get any errors?

Comment: I get an error: Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Net Sale (After Tax)").Orientation = xlDataField

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue adding fields with parentheses in their name: are you sure that exact name is in your column headings?  Check for leading/trailing spaces, etc.

Comment: I used the ```trim()``` function to get rid of any spaces and now everything works as expected. Thanks a ton.